# Can we make changes on screen/browser without using hooks in ReactJS. (In case of functional component)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I have created a toggle button which will show and hide the value variable. But I can't see the changes on the screen, Although console shows the value of 'show' is changing every time I click the 'Change Me' button.

```
import React from 'react'

export default function State(){
 let val = 4;
  let show = true;
  function changeMe(){
    show = !show;
    console.log(show);
  }
  return(
    <div>
      {show ? <span>{val}</span> : null}
      <br></br>
      <button onClick = {changeMe}>Change Me</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

What I understand about functional component is that they are stateless component and we can only present the state/props of them. Is this is the reason I can't create toggle button without hooks to render the changes. Please correct me If I am wrong or add on your answer/thought to clear my concept.

PS: I am new to React and learning concepts of React. So, it might be a silly question.

Comment: Why do you want to write a stateful function component without using hooks?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If someone doesn't know the concept of hooks, definitely this kind of thing came up in mind. I hope you got me.

Comment: I'm glad to say you understand correctly: They're stateless, if you don't use hooks. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I understand about functional component is that they are stateless component and we can only present the state/props of them. Is this is the reason I can't create toggle button without hooks to render the changes.

Yes. If you don't use hooks, function components are stateless. To have a stateful component, either:

- Use hooks, or
- Use a `class` component instead

Note that function components can have *props* without using hooks (and usually do). Props are basically state the parent element manages. The parent can even pass your function component a function it calls in response to an event that may make the parent component change the prop the function component uses (using state in the parent, via hooks or a `class` component). But props are distinct from state.

For instance, here's a function component with a `ticks` property updated by the parent:

```js
const {Component, useState, useEffect} = React;

function Child({ticks}) {
    return <div>{ticks}</div>;
}

class ClassParent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ticks: 0
        };
        this.onTick = this.onTick.bind(this);
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.timer = setInterval(this.onTick, this.props.interval || 1000);
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
    
    onTick() {
        this.setState(({ticks}) => {
            ++ticks;
            return {ticks};
        });
    }
    
    render() {
        return <Child ticks={this.state.ticks} />;
    }
}

function FunctionParent({interval = 1000}) {
    const [ticks, setTicks] = useState(0);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() =>{
            setTicks(t => t + 1);
        }, interval);
    }, []);

    return <Child ticks={ticks} />;
}

function Example() {
    return <div>
        <ClassParent interval={800} />
        <FunctionParent interval={400} />
    </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could also use React's Context to pass hooks from it as a prop.  Then you could call that function to update the state values inside of context.  Then changes would render and your component would still be stateless..

Comment: @Raythe - *"You could also use React's Context to pass hooks from it as a prop."* That's using hooks. :-)

Comment: So, basically what you are saying is that in the parent component I can make changes in a state using hooks and pass that state as a prop to the functional component and each time the state changes the same changes reflect in the functional component which uses props. Correct? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Exactly.

const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState();
<ChildComponent foo={foo} setFoo={setFoo} />

Comment: @T.J.Crowder true but outside of the child component's scope.

Comment: @JayantSharma - Right, exactly. State (in React terminology) is managed by the component itself (and function components can only do that with hooks), props are managed by the parent. When the parent changes the props, the child component is called to update itself based on the new props.